# how to export 4K video with KdenLive

Tags: kdenlive

I want to export 4K video from [Kdenlive](http://www.kdenlive.org/) in a format suitable for use with YouTube. I composed the project in Kdenlive using a 4K profile like the following:

[image]

At the point of rendering, I am unsure how to have Kdenlive output 4K video. The rendering settings now are as follows:

[image]

Could you advise me on how to export the video in 4K?

Comment: Just curious. What theme is that? (:

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and

1. I created a 4k profile the same way you did.
2. I created a custom rendering profile with the following contents that I called 'Lossless 4k MKV'

   ```
   acodec=ac3 ab=448k ar=44100 ac=2 vcodec=libx264 crf=15 rc-lookahead=60 coder=1 flags=+loop cmp=+chroma partitions=+parti8x8+parti4x4+partp8x8+partp4x4+partb8x8 me_method=umh subq=10 me_range=24 g=250 keyint_min=25 sc_threshold=40 i_qfactor=0.71 b_strategy=2 qcomp=0.6 qmin=0 qmax=51 qdiff=4 bf=8 refs=9 directpred=1 flags2=+mixed_refs+dct8x8+fastpskip+mbtree cqp=0 wpredp=2 trellis=2 weightp=2 deblock=1:0:0 direct=auto muxer=auto aspect=%dar
   ```
3. I converted it to 1080p as well with the following command:

   ```
   avconv -i 4k.avi -scale 1920x1080 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 15 1080p.mkv
   ```